# How do you write to Jazzy's index.html?

Tags: jazzy

When the Jazzy docs are generated, index.html appears mostly blank except for an "Authors" heading with nothing below it. The examples on the GitHub page show plenty of content in their [index.html](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/index.html)

How can I achieve this same effect and where is "Authors" coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `README.md` in the root directory of the project.